# Can't draw rect in python pygame

Tags: python, pygame, render, draw, rect

I'm just getting started with PyGame. Here, I'm trying to draw a rectangle, but it's not rendering.

Here's the whole program.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import random

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Rafi's Game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 500))




class Entity():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y


class Hero(Entity):

    def __init__(self):
        Entity.__init__
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), ((self.x, self.y), (50, 50)), 1)



hero = Hero()
#--------------Main Loop-----------------

while True:


    hero.draw()

    keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keysPressed[K_a]:
        hero.x = hero.x - 3
    if keysPressed[K_d]:
        hero.x = hero.x + 3
    if keysPressed[K_w]:
        hero.y = hero.y - 3
    if keysPressed[K_s]:
        hero.y = hero.y + 3

    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))





    #Event Procesing
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    #Event Processing End


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)
```

`self.x` and `self.y` are currently 0 and 0.
Note that this is not a finished program, all it should do is draw a red square on a green background that can be controled by the WASD keys.

Comment: Will it render if you include the `width` argument at the end?  E.g. `width=1`

Comment: Heh, doesn't work for me, either. :)  Turns out `rect` doesn't accept keyword arguments, so the optional last argument must be given without the keyword.  But either way, that's not your problem.

Comment: If you are sure that `self.x` and `self.y` are 0, and that `screen` is properly initialized, then I think you'll have to post a complete, self-contained minimal example that demonstrates the problem.  Without that, we're just speculating.

Comment: Can you post some more of your code?  I'd like to see where the display is being updated.

Comment: Posted the whole program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at a portion of your main loop:

```
while True:


    hero.draw()

    keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keysPressed[K_a]:
        hero.x = hero.x - 3
    if keysPressed[K_d]:
        hero.x = hero.x + 3
    if keysPressed[K_w]:
        hero.y = hero.y - 3
    if keysPressed[K_s]:
        hero.y = hero.y + 3

    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
```

Inside the Hero class's draw function, you are drawing the rect.  In the main loop, you are calling `hero.draw()`, and then after handling your inputs, you are calling `screen.fill()`.  This is drawing over the rect you just drew.  Try this:

```
while True:

    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    hero.draw()

    keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    ....
```

That will color the entire screen green, *then* draw your rect over the green screen.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't belive I made such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an extended comment and question than an answer.

The following draws a red square.  Does it work for you?

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = 320, 240
black = 0, 0, 0
red = 255, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(black)
    # Either of the following works.  Without the fourth argument,
    # the rectangle is filled.
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (10,10,50,50))
    #pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (10,10,50,50), 1)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: It sounds like you're probably not updating or flipping the display, then.

Comment: @Roboinventor: I don't know if my example working means the original problem is solved.  I suspect rafitufi has something wrong in his code, but without seeing more of it, who knows?

Comment: Oh, I thought that he meant he had used what your answer to fix his code and his code worked now

Answer (score 0):

Check these links:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect

And here have a some examples:

http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=pygame.draw.rect

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,width,height), thickness)

pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, 50, 50), 1)
```